# Windows 11 cast stopped after started

Tags: windows-11, screencasts, miracast

I'm not sure this is the right stack exchange site. But it seems it fit best here.

I tried to connect my Laptop (Lenovo Yoga X13 Gen 2, Windows 11) with my LG TV (OLED55CX8L, Web Os 4.30) via screen cast.

When I start casting (via Windowskey + K), the screensharing loads. But at the time you expect the screen is shown, the TV reports "Screensharing was stopped by MyMockDevice".

I tried the steps listed here: https://www.businessinsider.com/how-to-cast-windows-desktop-to-tv

How to get casting to work? On windows 10 it worked fine. Reinstall is not an option.

Comment: What is "MyMockDevice"?

Comment: any custom device name.

Comment: Have you upgraded to Windows 11 less than 10 days ago? If yes, you can still go back to Windows 10.